# how to give a string from user having space between it?

Tags: java

I want to give a sentence from standard input and my sentence might have a space between it. I want to split the string. How to take input from standard input device?

I can do it with hard coded string.

`String speech = "Four score and seven years ago";
String[] result = speech.split(" ");`

Comment: What is an "unsteady sentence"?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Can you post the current and expected output?

Comment: You want to spilt the user input sentance?

Comment: the sentence that user entered @tichodroma

Comment: Show us a sentence that can't be split with `\\s` and that you want to split.

Comment: same as my example in speech string. i want to split it . but the sentence doesn't definite and user must type it. @ vimal bera

Comment: i want to give that sentence form user . and it isn't exact sentence @tichodroma

Comment: no give a string from user with space between it .can i do that? @Varun

Comment: please don't give bad mark! help me! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take input from user with `nextLine()` method of `Scanner` class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SplitString 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in/*Taking input from standard input*/);
        System.out.print("Enter any string=");
        String userInput = scan.nextLine();//Taking input from user
        String splittedString[] = userInput.split(" ");//Splitting string with space
    }
}
```

Comment: Can i ask one more question? what does nextline do?

Comment: It reads line till it do not find line seprator. Here are more details http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()

Answer (score 0):

Store the input in a StringBuilder, line by line.

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in, "UTF-8")); 
    String line;
    line = reader.readLine();
```

Then you can split your result.

```
String[] result = line.split("\\s");
```

Comment: but my sentence is only one line .:-?

Comment: And do you want to split this line into strings containg only one word each?

Comment: yes. but pay attention that user must type sentence.

Comment: Changed it for one line only. reader.readline takes one line from the input. Then split line. If you don't understand look at Varun's answer.